# Press down on button to change the color of CGRect using a value in an array. How can this be accomplished?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cocoa, xcode8

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am working on a project in Xcode 8.0 using Swift 3.0. The application I am trying to develop is a life counter for Magic the Gathering for my class' final project. The first image is what appears on screen when the user navigates from the home screen of the app to the life counter screen.

Here's [a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zZpQ.jpg) to an image that shows what the user sees when they navigate from the application's home screen to this view.

You will see in the photo that there is the view controller, named lifeCounterViewController, and inside of that view controller are two other views. These views are named player1View and player2View respectively.

Inside each of those views a rectangle is being drawn. It is a member of the CGRect class. The following code is from a cocoa touch swift file. It contains the code that has my override of the draw function.

```
//
//  player1LifeCounterDrawing.swift

import UIKit

class player1LifeCounterDrawing: UIView {

    let MagicRed = UIColor.init(red: 247.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 146.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let Purple = UIColor.init(red: 102.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 204.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let Magenta = UIColor.init(red: 102.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let Orange = UIColor.init(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 166.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let Plum = UIColor.init(red: 179.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 89.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let Emerald = UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 102.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let Teal = UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 153.0/255.0, blue: 153.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let SlateBlue = UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 153.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let Forest = UIColor.init(red: 51.0/255.0, green: 153.0/255.0, blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let NavyBlue = UIColor.init(red: 51.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 153.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let MagicBlue = UIColor.init(red: 157.0/255.0, green: 216.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let MagicBlack = UIColor.init(red: 194.0/255.0, green: 179.0/255.0, blue: 180.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let MagicGreen = UIColor.init(red: 141.0/255.0, green: 203.0/255.0, blue: 158.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    var colorLibrary = [UIColor]()
    var index = 0
    func fillLibrary(library: [UIColor]) -> [UIColor]{
        let capture = [UIColor](arrayLiteral: MagicRed, MagicBlue, MagicGreen, MagicBlack, Purple, Magenta, Orange, Plum, Emerald, Teal, SlateBlue, Forest, NavyBlue )
        return capture
    }
    func calling(){
        colorLibrary = fillLibrary(library: colorLibrary)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect){
        calling()
        let lineWidth = CGFloat(3.0)
        let rectangle = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
            size: CGSize(width: bounds.maxX, height: bounds.maxY)
        )
        let rectPath = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: rectangle,
            byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner(rawValue: 0),
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        )
        rectPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
        rectPath.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.square
        if index >= colorLibrary.count{
            index = 0
        }
        colorLibrary[index].setFill()
        colorLibrary[index].setStroke()

        index += 1

        rectPath.stroke()
        rectPath.fill()
    }

}
```

Now this solution works, but it is ugly. As you can see whenever the draw function is called the array named, colorLibrary, is being reinitialized.

I fear that this is a large waste of memory and I need help finding a solution so that whenever the user presses down on a button a call to setNeedsDisplay() is made and the setStroke() and setFill() methods color is changed to reflect the color represented in the colorLibrary at [index].

How can this be accomplished?

Also keep in mind that the proposed solution needs to work for both player1View and player2View. I have only shown the code in player1View, but it is the same in player2View only the number identifying which view is which has changed.

Again, in my mind this is a large waste of memory, and I would like to have this fixed before Tuesday since that is when I need to present my application to my class. If I can't get a working solution by then I'll just go with this current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift supports *lazy initialisation* to, among other things, avoid the duplication you are concerned about. You can replace your `colorLibrary` with:

```
lazy var colorLibrary: [UIColor] = [self.MagicRed, self.MagicBlue, self.MagicGreen,
                                   self.MagicBlack, self.Purple, self.Magenta,
                                   self.Orange, self.Plum, self.Emerald, self.Teal,
                                   self.SlateBlue, self.Forest, self.NavyBlue]
```

Note this uses an array literal (`[` ... `]`).

Now the variable `colorLibrary` will be initialised on first use and its value retained.

(To be accurate the variable *may* be initialised more than once, in particular in multi-threaded scenarios, but this need not concern you.)

On another note you manage your index with code like:

```
  if index >= colorLibrary.count{
     index = 0
  }
  // use index...      
  index += 1
```

The common way to manage an index like this is to use *modular* arithmetic; that is arithmetic which wraps around, adding one to the maximum value results in the minimum value. (For a real world example consider an odometer or the counter on an electric meter, after reaching all 9's these cycle around to all 0's.)

Modular arithmetic can be perform using the mod operator `%`, which for this purpose you can think of as returning the *remainder* of a division. The above code outline becomes:

```
  // use index...      
  index = (index + 1) % colorLibrary.count
```

and the `if` is avoided.

HTH

Comment: I have marked this as the correct solution. Thank you for your time. I really enjoyed learning about lazy initialization, and how to use modulus division for my indexes. Shared this solution with others in my class and they thought it was great!

Answer (score 0):

You already have everything set up, an instance variable for the array of colours etc, but you're recreating this array with every draw cycle when every time except the first you probably needn't be.

Consider changing the call to calling() function at the start of draw(_:) so that you can reuse the previous array of colours.  This won't save any memory, but it will reduce the  number of unnecessary and repeated allocations, significantly improving efficiency.  best

```
if colorLibrary.count == 0 {
calling()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing the index inside of your draw code will result in increasing at every single draw (device rotation -> redraw, go to background and open again -> redraw, ...). But you only want to do it when pressing a button.

My suggestion is to extract the color and index functionality into a specialized class (because it is logic independent of ui, the view should only draw something not more). You can also use lazy loading to avoid to much object creations.

e.g.:

```
final class ColorLibrary {

    // increase index logic (including overflow handling)
    private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    func increaseIndex() {
        if currentIndex == colors.count - 1 {
            currentIndex = 0
        } else {
            currentIndex += 1
        }
    }

    // lazy loading: color array will be created only once and only if needed
    private var _colors: [UIColor]?
    private var colors: [UIColor] {
        if _colors == nil {
            _colors = [
                UIColor.init(red: 247.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 146.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 102.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 204.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 102.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 166.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 179.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 89.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 102.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 153.0/255.0, blue: 153.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 153.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 51.0/255.0, green: 153.0/255.0, blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 51.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 153.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 157.0/255.0, green: 216.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 194.0/255.0, green: 179.0/255.0, blue: 180.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor.init(red: 141.0/255.0, green: 203.0/255.0, blue: 158.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            ]
        }
        return _colors!
    }

    var currentColor: UIColor {
        get { return colors[currentIndex] }
    }

}
```

You can construct the object inside of your view now by:

```
    private(set) var colorLibrary: ColorLibrary = ColorLibrary()
```

Accessing the color inside of your draw:

```
    colorLibrary.currentColor.setFill()
```

At button press you may call now:

```
    cardView.colorLibrary.increaseIndex()
    cardView.setNeedsLayout()
```